# GuzzleHttp - 400 error exception but with curl working perfectly

Tags: guzzle6, guzzle

I'm calling a third party rest API with GuzzleHttp but it gives me a **400 Bad Request** every time.

Development environment:

1. **Laravel / PHP framework**
2. **Guzzle version in composer.json file -  "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"**
3. **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

Guzzle call to URL with data:

```
try{

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$res= $client->request('post',
            env('FLIGHT_API').'FlightSearch',
            ['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json' , 'Accept' => 'application/json'],'form_params' => $body]);

}catch (ClientException $e){



        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage().$e->getCode();

        return $response;

    }
```

Guzzle response:

```
{
"status": false,
"message": "Client error: `POST http://stagingapi.trip.com/Search` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n\ufeff<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3 (truncated...)\n400"
}
```

So, at last I tried same API with curl and it's working perfect and get result.

Curl code with URL and data:

```
$curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => env('FLIGHT_API').'FlightSearch',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "content-type: application/json",
                "Accept: application/json"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        //return $response;
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if($response){

            return json_decode($response , true);

        }

        return $err;
```

How can I determine where the fault is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
'json' => $body
```

instead of

```
'form_params' => $body
```

Comment: that's work for me but can you tell me what's the difference between ' fomr_params ' and 'json' ? and in which condition can use which one ?

Comment: It's [described in the docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params). `forms_params` is to send HTML forms, `json` to send JSON.

Comment: خدا پدر مادرت رو بیامرزه مشکلم حل شد بلامسیر